# Translation of the word/concept “trope”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

According to Wikipedia (Emphasis mine):

> A literary trope is the use of figurative language, via word, phrase or an image, for artistic effect such as using a figure of speech. The word trope has also come to be used for **describing commonly recurring literary and rhetorical devices, motifs or clichés in creative works**.

These tropes are present in all forms of media, some examples for tropes are:

- Fantasy story, the hero starts off as a farm boy.
- It’s eventually revealed that one of the main characters is actually royalty.
- In movies, to defuse a bomb, you have to “cut the red wire” and the bomb stops in the last second.
- Archetypal and generic "bad guys" like Nazis or Russians in American action movies.

So, how would I translate the following sentences?

> I didn't like the movie because they used too many predictable tropes.
>
> The author’s new book is a perfect example of the *Groundhog Day* trope: The protagonist is stuck repeating the same day over and over.
>
> When creating a narrative, using tropes can help subconsciously prime the reader for what to expect in the story.
>
> The website TV Tropes tracks a vast amount of tropes and makes it very easy to look them up.

I am aware that trope sometimes is translated to *Tropus* (auch *die Trope,* Plural *Tropen)* but I've never heard anyone use this in actual German conversation and in the literary context, it yields almost no google results. Is there a more common word or phrase that’s used instead?

Comment: you take a wiki article and leave out Topos and Motiv

Answer (score 10):

We (Germans) would probably use the word *Cliché/Klischee* or the corresponding adjective *klischeehaft*, as in

> Ich mochte den Film, aber dass die Bombe wieder in letzter Sekunde entschärft wurde, war sooo klischeehaft. *I enjoyed the movie but that the bomb got defused in the last second was so typical*

Comment: Or in the context of movies: *Filmklischee*. There is a Spiegel article about this phenomenon: https://www.spiegel.de/geschichte/filmklischees-wer-hustet-stirbt-a-948495.html

Comment: While Klischee was the first thing that came to my mind as well, it's only part of the overall ( literary ) trope concept (as the OP's definition shows). I also think Klischee has a negative connotation, while trope is a neutral term.

Comment: Hm, for me, trope has the same connotation as Klischee and of course depends on the context.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing that came to my mind when reading your question was "Klischee" (as already mentioned by @infinitezero). But as you said cliché is just one aspect of the word trope

> The word trope has also come to be used for describing commonly recurring literary and rhetorical devices, motifs or clichés in creative works.

For example, the ["Heroes Journey"-trope](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheHerosJourney) ("Lord of the Rings", Heitz' "Die Zwerge", etc) is a story pattern, but not a cliché (from my point of view). Tropes like the [Sibling Rivalry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SiblingRivalry) ("Cain & Abel", Schiller's "Die Räuber") are also more narrative motives than clichés.

I also think Klischee has a negative connotation, while trope is a neutral term.

---

Tropus on the other hand (as mentioned by @Wort-des-Tages) is the correct translation for your word. Unfortunately this word is widely unknown. Just take a look at the comments, but @Wort-des-Tages says it him/herself.

---

I think you have to look at how common the word is in the English-speaking world. do most people know it because of tvtropes.com and it's an rather uncommon word? If so, go with "Tropus". Is it a well-known word? Well, then you have to make a decision. "Klischee" as some kind of pars pro toto or maybe one of these contructions:

> typisches Motiv
>
> (literarische) Schablone
>
> typisches Erzählelement
>
> literarischer Topos (unusual as Tropus ^^)

Answer (score 0):

The English word *trope* is the almost identical to the German word *Tropen.* This is a technical term and almost no layman is going to understand what you are talking about. People studying literature or film studies (Literatur- or Filmwissenschaft) will.

With most of these sentences, Google Translate is going to work well.

> I didn’t like the movie because they used too many predictable tropes.
> Ich mochte den Film nicht, weil sie zu viele vorhersehbare Tropen verwendeten.
>
> The author’s new book is a perfect example of the *Groundhog Day* trope.
> Das neue Buch des Autors ist ein perfektes Beispiel für den Groundhog-Day-Trope.
>
> The website TV Tropes tracks a vast amount of tropes.
> Die Website TV Tropes verfolgt eine Vielzahl von Tropen.

There's a nice book about Tropes called *Logik der Tropen: Tiefensprachliche Redemodi im Denkweg Martin Heideggers*.
If you are interested, that might be a good place to start.

Sources:

- https://forum.dict.cc/forum-questions/detail-453257-x.html
- https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/Tropus
- https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tropen_Trope

Comment: If you talk to people who didn't study literature or film, though, they will think you are talking about the tropics.

Comment: *Google Translate is going to work well.* – Well, they got the gender of *-rope* wrong in the second example and *verfolgt* in the third one is overly literal. — I also strongly doubt that the book about Heidegger is a good place to start.

Comment: Der Singular im Deutschen ist _Tropus_, nicht *_Trope_

Comment: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tropen_Trope

Comment: Ich kenne sehr wohl den Singular _Trope_. Allerdings, zugegegebenermaßen, aus dem Altgriechischunterricht. Und ich würde es folglich auch endbetonen. (Laut Gemoll sind τρόπος und τροπή eh ziemlich dasselbe, aber bei letzterem steht explizit "gramm. t.t.: tropische, figürliche Ausdrucksweise, beim ersten nur "Redefigur". Kann man wohl vom Endverbraucher alles nicht verlangen :))